# Compare number formatting of two cells in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

My problem:

Cell A1: value =12 and the number property is general.
Cell A2: value =12 and the number property is number with 2 decimal points, so the number is shown as "12.00"

How can I validate if both cells have the same number property, either in `VBA` using macros or in any other way?

Comment: why would you want to compare number formatting instead of the actual values?

Comment: The actual values are also validated, Number formatting needs to be checked because the fields where Ranks are there the whole number should be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare their `NumberFormat` property:

```
If Range("A1").NumberFormat = Range("A2").NumberFormat Then
```

However, There are a number of different formats, including custom formats, that can be applied to cells that would make them look the same, without them having exactly the same NumberFormat value.

This means that comparing formats will never be as reliable as comparing the values. (It is also unusual to need to compare formats.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NumberFormat` method.

Using this code, with `12` in A1 (formatted as general) and `12` in B1 (formatted as 12.00)

```
Option Explicit
Sub Stuff()

    MsgBox Range("A1").NumberFormat
    MsgBox Range("B1").NumberFormat

End Sub
```

Will return messages of "General" and "0.00" respectively.

So using

```
If Range("A1").NumberFormat = Range("B1").NumberFormat Then
    -- do stuff here
End If
```

Will tell you if they are equal to one another or not.

Comment: You have mis-spelt NumberFormat.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are *really* concerned with the *values* of the cells. The `.NumberFormat` property simply masks how the *value* appears, visually, to the user of the spreadsheet.

So you can easily do an equivalence test on the two *values*, like:

```
Sub Test()

MsgBox [A1].Value = [A2].Value

End Sub
```

Or you could do this in the worksheet formula:

`=A1=A2`

That formula should return either `True` or `False`, and should ignore the cell's `formatting`.